# ASP.NET WebAPI `In` Validation Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created custom validation attribute that will be used to validate model. It allows me to specify values that are valid for specific field.
Here is my code:

```
public sealed class InAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{1} is invalid value for {0}.";

    private readonly int[] testArray;
    private int _toTest;

    public InAttribute(int[] @in) : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        if (!@in.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("in");
        }

        testArray = @in;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, _toTest);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " cant be null");
        }
        _toTest = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        if (!testArray.Contains(_toTest))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Then I can use it like so:

```
public class RequestHelpBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [In(new []{1,3,4,7},ErrorMessage = "{1} is invalid value.")]
    [Display(Name = "Typ")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get review on this.

My questions are:

1. Is it build right?
2. If there are places to optimize please let me know.

Comment: @BCdotWEB as I wrote my code is written and it is working. If part 2 and 3 is invalid I can remove it, but as I wrote they are about optimization of my code, not about something not working.

Comment: @BCdotWEB already fixed :) sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if (!@in.Any())
> {
>     throw new ArgumentNullException("in");
> }
> ```

This won't work the way you expect it.

It should be either C# 6

```
 if (@in?.Any())
```

or for previous versions

```
 if (@in == null || !@in.Any())
```

---

> ```
> return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " cant be null");
> ```

Why the empty string at the beginning?

---

One time you do

> ```
> return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " cant be null");
> ```

and the other time

> ```
> return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
> ```

I thought you forgot to use the `FormatErrorMessage` in the first case but it produces a completely different error message.

Create another method and name it accordignly like `FormatNullValueErrorMessage` and the other one `FormatNotInErrorMessage`.

---

> ```
> ErrorMessage = "{1} is invalid value.")
> ```

I don't think this parameter has any value and is actually very error prone because the user of this attribute has to know that he can use the `{1}` and what it means. I'd stick to an automatic message about the value not beeing allowed.

---

> ```
> private readonly int[] testArray;
> ```

I would rename this field to soemthing like `_allowedValues`. As I first time saw it I thought it's a test code. Reserve the *test* for tests or really rare cases when there is no better word.

---

> ```
> _toTest = Convert.ToInt32(value);
> ```

It's not necessary to store the value locally. Pass it as a paramter to the `FormatXErrorMessage`.

Comment: Thank You for review. I'll try to fix all mistakes and I'll add my code as edit in question so that You could take a second look.

Answer (score 1):

While writing any attribute, please add the information about where the attribute will be used, like below.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class InAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     //TODO: your code here
}
```